# How do I re-Install Ubuntu Server on separate LVM partition than my data

Tags: installation, server, partitioning, lvm, alternate

I have three logical volumes in a single volume group spread across two physical volumes.

```
V1:root
V2:srv
V3:swap_1
```

All of ubuntu is on `root` and all of the data I care about keeping is on `srv`

For various reasons, I'd like to re-install Ubuntu Server to get fresh start.

How can I replace Ubuntu on `root` without removing my data on `srv`?

I'd prefer not to have to copy everything over from the backup, if possible, especially since I might have to do this again in the future...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure you can just install ubuntu server, and in the setup, just select install on root, and don't do anything to srv

Comment: Pretty sure this wasn't clear when I popped the CD in last time.  I'll give it another go and provide more detail in the question if necessary.

Comment: I haven't installed ubuntu server in a while, last time was at least a year ago I think. I think you may have to select manually configure disk layout or similar

Answer (score 1):

Run the Ubuntu Server installation and choose manual configuration when it gets to the partitioning step. Select your `root` volume for Ubuntu and mark it for reformatting. Select your `srv` volume to be mounted on `/srv` and make sure it is not marked for reformatting. Alternatively, don't select it at all and add it to your `/etc/fstab` after installation. Select your `swap` volume to be used as swap.